# How to make GridCacheStore-backed get() store its result in the cache

Tags: caching, gridgain

When I use a `GridCacheStore`-backed cache, the first `get()` may take a long time, because internally the `GridCacheStore` will perform calculations / slow search etc.

The second `get()` on *that* node will be quick because the result has been cached by *that* node.

However, the `get()` on other node is still slow because the result is not being replicated. How to make this replicated? I've set `cacheMode=REPLICATED`.

My config:

```
<bean parent="cache-template">
    <property name="name" value="yagoEntityByLabel" />
    <property name="cacheMode" value="REPLICATED" />
    <property name="atomicityMode" value="ATOMIC" />
    <property name="distributionMode" value="NEAR_PARTITIONED" />
    <property name="backups" value="1" />
    <property name="store">
        <bean class="id.ac.itb.ee.lskk.lumen.core.yago.YagoEntityByLabelCacheStore" />
    </property>
    <property name="swapEnabled" value="false" />
    <property name="evictionPolicy">
        <bean class="org.gridgain.grid.cache.eviction.lru.GridCacheLruEvictionPolicy">
            <property name="maxSize" value="10000" />
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>
```

The workaround is to not use `GridCacheStore`-backed but to use `put()` instead, but there's a lot of typing and it's not atomic, since the logic will be:

```
@Nullable value = cache.get(key);
if (value == null) {
   value = calculateHeavily(key);
   cache.put(key, value);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GridGain (as most other data grids) does not replicate on Get operation - it simply loads data into cache. Your workaround using Put operation is good.

To make it atomic (if you need to do so), you can wrap your code into transaction, like so:

```
try (GridCacheTx tx = cache.txStart()) {
   @Nullable value = cache.get(key);
   if (value == null) {
      value = calculateHeavily(key);
      cache.put(key, value);
   }

   tx.commit();
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Dmitriy ... Now I know how to use transaction properly :) Previously I'd use `lock()` and `unlock()`, which seemed hacky. However, can this very useful snippet be part of GridGain API? Or at least a static method in official GridGain utility class?

Comment: In case this is helpful to others, here's the transaction example:  https://github.com/ceefour/lumen-kb/blob/b8445fbebd227fb7ac337c758a60badb7ecd3095/cli/src/main/java/id/ac/itb/ee/lskk/lumen/yago/AnswerYagoFactTests.java#L208 :)

Comment: @HendyIrawan GridGain already ships with transaction example. Did you have something else in mind for the snippet?